# Using the Title() in the CSV file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have a CSV file which contains an Address field. The CSV file has Addresses outlined as the following in everything caps but I need your assistance in using the title() snippet on the append(row[1]). I have tried doing:

```
  append.title(row[1]) but it does not work.

  In the CSV File --------------Needs to be:

  1234 PRESTON ROAD  -------- 1234 Preston Road
  1245 JACKSON STREET ------- 1245 Jackson Street
  8547 RAINING COURT ------- 8547 Raining Court


with open('C:\\Users\\Jake\\Desktop\\My Files\\Python Files\\PermitData.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next (reader)
    data = list(reader)

PermitData = []

for row in data:
   PermitData.append(row[0]),PermitData.append(row[1]),PermitData.append(row[2]),
   PermitData.append(row[3]),PermitData.append(row[4]),PermitData.append(row[5]),
   PermitData.append(row[6])

results = PermitData

for result in results:
    print result

f.close()
```

The reason I am iterating over every row in the CSV file is the need to save the edited CSV file as a temp file before replacing the original with the edited one. I am not that articulate with Python as I am learning by doing actual projects so please forgive any stupidity in the question and coding. Please provide your kind advice and assistance.

Comment: The better would be adding some lines of your file and what you expect as output

Comment: Thanks ettanany, I have edited the post to show how the Addresses are outlined in the CSV file and how I request the Addresses to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will create a new file named `output.csv` with the output that you asked for:

```
import csv

with open('C:\\Users\\Jake\\Desktop\\My Files\\Python Files\\output.csv', 'w') as out:
    with open('C:\\Users\\Jake\\Desktop\\My Files\\Python Files\\PermitData.csv', 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        out.write(next(reader)[0].replace('\t', ' ') + '\n')
        data = list(reader)
        for item in data:
            item = item[0].split(' ')
            out.write(' '.join(
                [item[0],
                item[1].title(),
                item[2].title()]) + '\n')
```

If what you want is just to print the result, try as follows:

```
import csv

results = []

with open('permitData.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)
    data = list(reader)
    for item in data:
        item = item[0].split(' ')
        results.append(' '.join(
            [item[0],
            item[1].title(),
            item[2].title()]))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> for result in results:
...     print result
...
1234 Preston Road
1245 Jackson Street
8547 Raining Court
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to call `title()` on the string you want to convert to Title Case. This should work:

```
append(row[1].title())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
PermitData = []

with open('C:\\Users\\Jake\\Desktop\\My Files\\Python Files\\PermitData.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    headers = next (reader)

    for row in reader:
        row = row[:1]+ [row[1].title()] + row[2:] # Assuming row[1] is your address field you need in a title case.
        PermitData.append(row)


for result in PermitData:
    print result
```

You should also note that you don't need to call `f.close()` when you are using the `with` syntax for opening a file.
The file gets closed automatically once you exit `with`